# Change the coefficients in matrix decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

**Part 1:** Suppose $A=\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i v_i v_i^\top$, where $\sigma\ge 0$ is a non-negative real number (singular value) and $v_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector. Suppose  $A$ is positive semidefinite. Is that true that $B:=\sum_{i=1}^n\eta_i v_i v_i^\top$ (where $\eta_i = p_i \times \sigma_i, p_i>0 $) is also positive semidefinite? In other words, we just multiply the singular values by a positive number.

**Part 2:** Now let $A=\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i v_i w_i^\top$ where $\sigma\ge 0$ is a non-negative real number and $v_i\in\mathbb{R}^n,w_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are vectors. Again, suppose  $A$ is positive semidefinite. Is that true that $B:=\sum_{i=1}^n\eta_i v_i w_i^\top$ (where $\eta_i = p_i \times \sigma_i, p_i>0 $) is also positive semidefinite?

Any comment or response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:  evaluate $x^T Bx$ in terms of what you've got, and see that it is $\ge0$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We have $x^\top B x = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \sigma_i x^\top v_i v_i^\top x$. We know $x^\top A x = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i x^\top v_i v_i^\top x \ge 0$. This is saying the sum of some terms is positive(but each term may not be positive). I do not see why the sum should still be positive when we change the coefficients?

Comment: Ah...I see. I guess we have $x^\top B x = \sum p_i \sigma_i (x^\top v_i)^2$ which is sum of positive terms and is positive. Is that right?

Comment: Indeed.  You have non-negative numbers, you multiply them and add them, and you are left with nonnegative numbers.

Comment: Thanks again. I revised  my question to include part 2. Can we say the same thing in part 2?